# How use for loop for confidence interval in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, confidence-interval

I want to use a for loop to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the mean of humidity by month in R,

```
for(i in 1:12){
  aa<-atmos_1995%>% group_by(month)%>% summarize(average=mean(temp))

  bb<-atmos_1995%>% group_by(month)%>% summarize(sd=sd(temp))

  lower_vector <-aa - 1.96 *bb/ sqrt(length(atmos_1995)) 
  upper_vector <- aa + 1.96 * bb / sqrt(length(atmos_1995))
  confi <- c(lower_vector[i], upper_vector[i])
  print(confi)
}
```

how can I change the code to have intervals for the mean of each month?

Comment: There is no need to use a loop.  You can calculate the by-month CIs (assuming your previous methodology makes this a valid approach) by including the calculation within your call to `summarize`.  Also, note that `length(atmos_1995)` most likely gives the incorrect denominator: it's the number of rows in the whole data frame, not the number of rows relating to the current month.  Without a minimal *reproducible* example, there's little more to say.

Comment: it is asked to use for loop